Dynamic update of add_qty parameter in Odoo eCommerce product details page
I'm customizing an Odoo eCommerce website and I need to modify the add_qty parameter in the product details page dynamically via a URL parameter. I'm extending the WebsiteSale class to achieve this.
Here's my code snippet:
class WebsiteSaleCustom(WebsiteSale):
    def _prepare_product_values(self, product, category, search, **kwargs):
        values = super()._prepare_product_values(product, category, search, **kwargs)
        values['add_qty'] = int(kwargs.get('add_qty', 1))
        return values

This solution works as expected upon the first load of the product details page. However, the issue arises when attempting to dynamically update the add_qty parameter.
Suppose i hit this link
http://localhost:8069/shop/black-shoe?add_qty=5
Quantity will set 5. For first time, it is setting 5 but if i change quantity it not changing in quantity field. It's remaining 5.
Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

It is unclear what exactly you need; could you possibly be more specific? Did you mean that each product should have the ability to set add_qty dynamically?

Suppose i hit this link
http://localhost:8069/shop/black-shoe?add_qty=5
Quantity will set 5. For first time, it is setting 5 but if i change quantity it's not changing in quantity field. It's remaining 5.

To address issues related to outdated or incorrect data being fetched by Odoo due to caching, you can use the method request.env.registry._clear_cache() before applying your solution. This method clears the cache, ensuring that Odoo fetches fresh data.
from odoo.http import request
from odoo.addons.website_sale.controllers.main import WebsiteSale


class WebsiteSaleCustom(WebsiteSale):
    def _prepare_product_values(self, product, category, search, **kwargs):
        request.env.registry._clear_cache()
        values = super()._prepare_product_values(product, category, search, **kwargs)
        values['add_qty'] = int(kwargs.get('add_qty', 1))
        return values


I am getting this error.
AttributeError: 'Registry' object has no attribute 'clear_cache'

Please try  request.env.registry._clear_cache()
